# I'm getting a process memory usage using PerformanceCounter. How can i display the memory usage in the same units as in task manager?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;

            if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
            {
                e.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("GameCapture");

                    PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();
                    performanceCounter.CategoryName = "Process";
                    performanceCounter.CounterName = "Working Set";
                    performanceCounter.InstanceName = processes[0].ProcessName;
                    worker.ReportProgress(0, ((uint)performanceCounter.NextValue() / 1024).ToString("N0"));
                }
            }
        }
```

What i get is in my program 530.7 MB 
In task manager same process i see it around 445.3 MB

Why is the big difference between my program and the task manager ?
what should i do if i wanted to display in my program the task manager value ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Working set* represents the size of all pages belonging to the process. This variable shrinks and grows when pages are moved to the page file and when they are called back into main memory, respectively. It doesn't refer exclusively to memory your application uses, as such some shared memory might be counted twice in this metric. Look [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-task-manager-memory-columns-mean#1TC=windows-7) for more info.

*Working set - Private* is probably the metric you are looking for. Windows Task manager uses working set private as its memory usage metric. It doesn't concern itself with the page file, so you get an accurate representation of the impact on your physical ram, and it doesn't count shared objects twice.

```
PerformanceCounter performanceCounter = new PerformanceCounter();

performanceCounter.CategoryName = "Process";
performanceCounter.CounterName = "Working Set - Private";
performanceCounter.InstanceName = processes[0].ProcessName;
```